# closest successor of the Lubavitch Rebbi today

Tags: chabad, chassidic-rebbe, rabbis

who is the closest person today to being the successor of the Lubavitch Rebbi?

i.e. who is the biggest (greatest scholar) Chabad Rabbi to ask questions to about Chabad issues.

Comment: Ray:  Your first and second questions are very different. Your second question is also unclear: does "Chabad issues" mean "Chabad Chassidus?" Does it mean "Chabad social, communal, or cultural issues?" Those might have very different answers.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, very related, but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rabbis Moshe Kotlarsky and Rabbi Yehuda Krinsky currently head the Lubavitch institutions. [See more here, including a discussion of their succession plans](http://forward.com/articles/177251/fast-growing-chabad-asks-who-will-be-leader-for-n/?p=all).

As for which Chabad Rabbi is known as the greatest scholar today, I don't know but the one who comes to my mind immediately would be [Rabbi Adin Steinzaltz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adin_Steinsaltz), whose name had been briefly floated by some outsiders as a great choice for an eighth Lubavitcher rebbe.

Comment: @Shmuel And many Lubavitchers might agree with you. The key word in Shalom's second paragraph is "outsiders."

Comment: Definitely Reb Yoel Rabbi Adin is a Lay leader not rebbe Material plus he does not come from the Family

Comment: @YUASK - R' Yoel Kahn is related to the Rebbe?? That's the first I've heard that; are you sure?

Comment: no he is NOT but still more qualified

Comment: R' Adin Steinzaltz would be great eighth Rebbe!

Answer (score 1):

Reb Yoel Kahn is "the" giant master in chassidus

Comment: What's a giant master?

Comment: In all chissidus or just chabad?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think that he's answering the second question.

Comment: Sholy, can you say more about why?  Is this your personal opinion, or does somebody with authority say so (who?), or what?  Thanks.